# NHibernate : Delete a record in many-to-many relationshio

Tags: nhibernate, orm

I have a object `Customer`, this object has an `ISet` list of `Contact`. When I delete a `Customer` I'd like to delete the `Contact`.

I use the mapping below, I tried all option in cascade but still have this problem :
*The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK4FF8F4B29499D0A4". The conflict occurred in database "MyDB", table "dbo.Contact", column 'Customer'.*

**The mapping `Customer`**

```
<set name="Contacts" table="CustomerContact" cascade="save-update">
    <key column="Customer" />
    <many-to-many class="Contact" column="Contact" />
</set>
```

**The mapping `Contact`**

```
<many-to-one name="Customer" column="Customer" not-null="true" />
```

Comment: my guess was to set all-delete-orphan, but it seems you already tried that. Try looking at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302720/how-to-delete-child-object-in-nhibernate/302860#302860.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is strange that you have [bidirectional](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-associations-bidirectional) association between customer and contact mapped like that. If Customer can be associated with multiple Contacts, and vice versa, you should have many-to-many on both sides. But you have many-to-one at Contact side. And you mention that you want to cascade deletes to Contact.

Perhaps you should consider mapping Contacts collections as **one-to-many**? Try this for Customer mapping, note [inverse](http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/colinyates/entry/hibernates_bizzare_interpretation/) attribute.

```
<set name="Contacts" 
     table="CustomerContact" 
     inverse="true" 
     cascade="all-delete-orphan" >

    <key column="Customer" />
    <one-to-many class="Contact" />
</set>
```

With this Contact mapping:

```
<many-to-one name="Customer" column="Customer" />
```

You will also have to 'chase the pointers': null out Customer.Contact when corresponding Contact is removed from Customer.Contacts collection.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry working 100% :) Sometimes it's not easy to understand all properties (inversion, ...) in NHibernate

Answer (score 0):

having the two propeties

```
 inverse="true"
```

and

```
 cascade="all-delete-orphan"
```

is the key..

apart from this you can as well do this while deleting the customer object:

```
customer.Contacts.Clear();
Session.Delete(customer);
```